# How do I normalize this wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, normalization

I need to find the normalisation constant $A$ for the  wave function:

$$
\psi\left(x\right) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        A  &\: \frac{-a}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{4}\\
        0 &\: {\rm otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
Could I get a hint on answering this question?

I think I am supposed to use the following but I'm not sure.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|\psi\left(x\right)\right|^2 \, dx = 1$$

Comment: what happens when you put your $\psi$ in the integral?

Comment: Use the integral you've written. Hint: Outside the interval $[-a/4,a/4]$, $\psi (x)=0$ so the integral outside this interval is also zero. That leaves you only one term...

Comment: Using a/4 and -a/4 as the upper and lower limits, i got A = 2/a. Would that be right?

Comment: You would actually find $AA^* = |A|^2 = 2/a$. You can then determine $A$ up to an overall phase $e^{i\delta}.$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\d}{\;\mathrm{d}}$You should straightforward take the integral that you mentioned:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left| \psi\right|^2 \d x =\int_{-a/4}^{a/4} AA^* \d x + \int_{-\infty}^{-a/4} 0 \d x + \int_{a/4}^\infty 0 \d x =1$$

I won't do the integral and calculate $A$ because it is trivial to do therefore I leave the rest to you.